# Is there a comprehensive Java Metro and WCF interoperability website, technique or resource?

Tags: java, wcf, wcf-binding, java-metro-framework, wcf-interoperability

I'm looking for a general purpose mapping of WCF configurations, and the appropriate Java Metro configuration.

Is there any resource that will assist in correlating the bindings and security options of one to the other?

Comment: Don't know about JAVA. However for interopability WCF can produce WSDL for JAVA to consume and VS can consume WSDL for generating proxy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no complete guide to this - there are many delicate details and a small change in configuration in one side can make or break everything. If you have a specific Metro configuration that you want the WCF equivalent to please publish it in this or a new question. If you do want something more general try the [WCF Interop Bindings](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/test-drive-shiny-new-wcf-interop.html).

Comment: This was what I knew I forgot!  Hopefully there are other resources out there